# How to pass dynamic value to JSON as a API request in flutter flow?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

I have two page

1. Login/Registration Page as of now
2. OTP Verification Page

API has been created and in api, we are passing phone number as request and gets otp as response. However i would like your help to know how should i able to pass the phoneNumber textfield data to APIcall json request in flutterflow?

If there is anyway or any documentation will be really helpful?

I have tried with variable method, however i was not able to pass it to json.
I have also tried jsonpath method, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Define dynamic part of API url with brackets

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/[postId]
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=[postId]
```

then create the variable (postId) with the same name. When adding the API call, it is required to add these variables.

See [API Calls 101](https://docs.flutterflow.io/data-and-backend/api-calls/api-calls-101) for details.